# How to persist old data on database until it is approved by admin to update it?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have information of members and can update their information. But the information must be approved by admin to let the information be updated.

Where to store data until it is verified? What can be its design in database?

My Approach:

1. duplicate the table of members and use that as storage for pending status and only update the original data after approved by admin. But this approach goes against the database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer if you don't want to go against the database design.

1. As mentioned earlier on the question you can do by duplication of the same table and store the new data and don't update the real table until approved.
2. make a new `json field` on the table which stores new value to be updated. After admin approves the data which can be shown from the `json field`; update the table and set `json field` to null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest just to have an `active` column that defaults to `false` that only Admins update. Then have `AND active=1` as part of queries.

Comment: Can you explain more. With the given answer, the old data is not persisted but only status if the data is verified or not.

Comment: I would have a 'timestamp' column and an 'approved' column. The 'active' row is then the latest approved one.